# How to make md-hint align center (material2)

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

How to center text in `<md-hint> </md-hint>` inside of `<md-input-container></md-input-container>`?

align=end works perefctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried few tricks but the only way I was able to move the text towards the center was by using `margin-left`.

`<md-hint style="margin-left: 35%"> </md-hint>` will move the text somewhat towards the center.